# jQuery — Multiple content sliders on one page, only move one at a time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery content slider that will eventually look like this old 37Signals  tourpage for Basecamp: http://cl.ly/2K2l1e010w0b3q1g261N (sadly, they changed the site TODAY when the updated Basecamp).

I basically want to have multiple content sliders on one page.  Currently clicking the links in one sidebar makes **both** content areas slide.

And the fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/dm2dn/

Thanks for the help

Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something tells me there's a cleaner way to do this, however the following works. It finds the index of the link clicked, and then does the slider animation based on that. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dm2dn/1/)** example.

jQuery:
    //handle nav click
    $(".nav a").click(function(e) {

```
    //stop browser default
    e.preventDefault();

    //remove on states for all nav links
    $(".nav a").removeClass("on");

    //add on state to selected nav link
    $(this).addClass("on");

    //set margin of slider to move
    if ($(".nav a").index(this) <= 4) {
        $(".slider:eq(0)").animate({
            marginLeft: margins[$(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]]
        });
    } else {
        $(".slider:eq(1)").animate({
            marginLeft: margins[$(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]]
        });
    }
});​
```

Note that the feeling I have about an easier way probably involves changing the layout and adding other elements to wrap the content separately.

**UPDATE**

Here's new jQuery to handle any number of groups and links:

```
//handle nav click
$(".group a").click(function(e){

    //stop browser default
    e.preventDefault();

    //remove on states for all nav links
    $(".nav a").removeClass("on");

    //add on state to selected nav link
    $(this).addClass("on");

    //set margin of slider to move
    $(this).parents('.group').find('.slider').animate({
        marginLeft: margins[$(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]]
    });                    
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dm2dn/2/)**. The jQuery changes are minor and the only HTML changes were wrapping each group of list/divs in a wrapper div with the class of group like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="thumb1"><a href="#panel1" title="Panel 1">Panel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel2">Panel 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel3">Panel 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel4">Panel 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel5">Panel 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panels">
        <div class="slider">
            <div id="panel1">
                <p>From this day forward, Flight Control will be known by two words:
                &#39;Tough&#39; and &#39;Competent.&#39; </p>
                <p>It&#39;s just mind-blowingly awesome. I apologize, and I wish I was
                more articulate, but it&#39;s hard to be articulate when your mind&#39;s
                blown—but in a very good way.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="panel2">
                <p>From this day forward, Flight Control will be known by two words:
                &#39;Tough&#39; and &#39;Competent.&#39; Tough means we are forever accountable
                for what we do or what we fail to do. We will never again compromise
                our responsibilities. </p>
                <p>Every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there--on
                a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="panel3">
                <p>These words are the price of admission to the ranks of Mission
                Control.</p>
                <p>It&#39;s just mind-blowingly awesome. I apologize, and I wish I was
                more articulate, but it&#39;s hard to be articulate when your mind&#39;s
                blown—but in a very good way.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="panel4">
                <p>From this day forward, Flight Control will be known by two words:
                &#39;Tough&#39; and &#39;Competent.&#39; Tough means we are forever accountable
                for what we do or what we fail to do. </p>
                <p>Look again at that dot. That&#39;s here. That&#39;s home. That&#39;s us.
                On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard
                of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. </p>
            </div>
            <div id="panel5">
                <p>The view of the Earth from the Moon fascinated me—a small disk,
                240,000 miles away. </p>
                5
                <p>The view of the Earth from the Moon fascinated me—a small disk,
                240,000 miles away. </p>
                5 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you could even suggest a more straightforward way, I'd appreciate it.  I can't really follow what you're doing here with .index() — and problems seem to arise when I increase the number of items in the sidebar list. Thanks

Comment: .index() is determining which link was clicked. <=4 catches the first group of links, >4 is the second group. Are you open to modifying the DOM?

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite open to modifying the way things are setup. I'm fairly certain I don't have them done very well at the moment. I'm not sure, for example, how well index() is going to work—I won't always have 4 items in the list. So it isn't particularly robust. Any better ideas?   Thanks!

Comment: Yup, give me an hour or two and I'll be back to answer.

Comment: Wow. THANKS so much for this. Extremely kind of you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach that will help you manage this is to insulate each of the instances within a $.each loop. Here's some pseudo code that should help explain

```
$('.myModuleWrapper').each(function(){
        var $this=$(this);      

        /* now when attach handlers we only search within current instance*/
        var $myClicker=$this.find('.myClickerClass');       
        var $myContent=$this.find('.myContentClass');       


        $myClicker.find('.myClickerClass').click(function(){
            $myContent.doSomething();
        });                               

})
```